# Deadlock exceptions in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

So I have been getting a large number of deadlock exceptions while trying to import data into a fresh database and I'd like to know how to avoid them and what thresholds will cause these deadlocks.

The import script calls the REST batch API to add followers, with all the follows relationship for each node in a single batch.

```
START left=node:node_auto_index(uname={from}), 
right=node:node_auto_index(uname={to})
CREATE left-[r:FOLLOWS]->right
```

I am creating 5340 relationships on 2200 nodes.  Most nodes follow just a few others, but some active nodes are following around a hundred other nodes.

I imagine the deadlock is happening because I am trying to batch insert all the follows relationship for a specific node in one batch.  Is it deadlocking because it's wrapped up in a batch api transaction?  If I take it out of the batch will it not deadlock?

Will this kind of deadlocking occur in production as well under normal usage?  In every day use we won't be bulk importing all the relationships for a single node, but I imagine two people can try to follow the same person at the same time.

Anyways, what do I do to avoid and how can I make sure this won't happen in live every day production use?

Comment: which version of neo4j do you run on?  i got some auto indexing problems on 1.9: my query select suddenly had stopped at 70k out of 300k node select loop, with high CPU and memory usage for several hours until i killed it. than i rather re-programmed my code to omit the auto index and it worked.

Comment: v 1.9 m1.  I got it to not deadlock if I wrap up the creation of all 5340 relationships into one batch transaction.  The relationships don't have an auto index..

Comment: If things are not clearing up, maybe you can raise an issue on this at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues ?